# Decompress .Z files in apache nifi

Tags: compression, apache-nifi

I have some files in .Z format on Linux system. I want to transfer uncompressed files to hdfs.

But '''compresscontent''' processor not supports .Z format.

Is there any way to do so in nifi.

Comment: You need to use `ExecuteStreamCommand` to executes an external command. Wrap decompress logic inside bash/shell/python script and call it using  `ExecuteStreamCommand`

Answer (score 0):

If your Linux system has the uncompress command, likely a script that runs gzip, then you can use that to decompress .Z files.